# How to open a link to new browser? if this link already open in new browser then refresh that open tab instead of opening new tab

Tags: javascript, html, hyperlink, cross-browser, href

I'm trying to open link in **microsoft-edge** browser from IE browser. if this link is already opened in microsoft-edge browser then refresh that open tab instead of opening new tab.

Comment: So what excatly have you tried so far

Comment: I'm able to open in new browser from IE but, it's not opening existing one if already opened.  like <a href="microsoft-edge:https://www.w3schools.com" target="newTab">This is a link</a>